# How do you use the number sign in a Twitter share URL?

Tags: html, twitter

I have a twitter share link on my page. The URL I would like to share is the following format:

```
http://example.com/something#open,this.html#first
```

But when I do this in the following code:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20World&amp;hashtags=example&amp;url=http://example.com/something#open,this.html#first" target="_blank" >Twitter</a>
```

The **#** symbol escapes the URL. Causing my sharing message to be:

```
Hello World http://example.com/something #example
```

How can I include the **#** symbol in my URL when sharing?

**UPDATE**

I was able to replace `%23` for the first URL. When I do this I get the Tweet:

```
Hello World http://example/com.something#open,this.html
```

If I use the same `%23` for the second **#**, the entire URL does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HTML Code for #. 
Here's the code:

```
&#35;
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, Eric. I tried using `%23` in place of the # symbol, but that would only work for the first **#** then would still escape the URL on the second **#**.

Comment: Did you try replacing the # symbol with '&#35;'? Also the comma in your URL is not valid. That could be an issue as well.